# XML Error: "XML document structures must start and end within the same entity."

Tags: java, xml, servlets

I'm making servlets, but following is the XML file of my web app. The JavaBeans compiler generates this error:

> [Fatal Error] :15:1: XML document structures must start and end within the same entity.
>   C:\Users\Zedfn\Documents\NetBeansProjects\Assignment2\nbproject\build-impl.xml:1045: Deployment error: Tomcat configuration file C:\Users\Zedfn\Documents\NetBeansProjects\Assignment2\web\META-INF\context.xml seems to be broken. Please make sure it is parseable and valid.
>   See the server log for details.
>   BUILD FAILED (total time: 0 seconds)

This is my XML code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<Context path="/Assignment2"/>
<wep-app>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>FormServlet</servlet-name>      
        <servlet-class>myServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>FormServlet</servlet-name>   
        <url-pattern>/formServlet</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>        
</wep-app>
```

What's wrong with this code?

Comment: Answer is withing the error message itself. After the default XML header, the first entity should cover the entire XML, by XML rules if your first node is the "Context", everything else should be inside it

Comment: how to do that?

Comment: Shouldn't it be `web-app` instead of `wep-app`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your XML code starting node is context so add  closing node for this at the end of the code.
Remove (/) from starting node also.